# Format Significant Digits in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I need to format values to the correct significant digits when given a value and an absolute error.

This is easy when the error is less than 1: 123.5879 +- 0.54889 is easily converted to 123.59 +- 0.55 via

`Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00":              Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00"`

However, I also need it to work for errors greater than 1: For 423423 +- 2341 it should convert to 423400 +-2300

I do not want to round the values in the cell, I will be using them for further calculation and do not want to potentially lose accuracy.  I want to change only the formatting.

Current code segment below; Cases 3,4,5 are where the problem is.  (If there's a completely different way to do this which accomplishes the goal of displaying the correct number of digits without changing the values, I'm open to that too.)

Thanks

```
Dim SigFig As Integer
SigFig = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Log(Err_Rng) / Log(10), 1)

Select Case SigFig
    Case Is < -5: Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000E+00":       Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0E+00"
    Case -5:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0000000":         Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0E+00"
    Case -4:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000000":          Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000000"
    Case -3:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00000":           Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00000"
    Case -2:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0000":            Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0000"
    Case -1:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000":             Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000"
    Case 0:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00":              Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Case 1:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0":               Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    Case 2:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.":                Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0."
    Case 3:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0":                 Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0"
    Case 4:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0":                 Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0"
    Case 5:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0":                 Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0"
    Case Is > 5: Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000E+00":        Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0E+00"
End Select
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can do what you want with formatting alone.  You could use a custom numberformat and display the formatted value while keeping the underlying value (but you'd need to update that whenever the cell value changes)

Comment: Your example of errors greater than 1 is showing rounding to the nearest hundred. I don't know any way to do that using numberformatting.  You can round to the nearest thousand, but not ten or hundred. Suggest you consider a different approach either involving that, or having your "display" columns different from your data columns.

Answer (score 0):

As said before you may use a custom format but you will need to update whenever the cell value changes.

```
      Dim SigFig As Integer
      Dim val As Double
      Dim Val_Rng As Range
      Dim Err_Rng As Range
      Set Val_Rng = Range("A1")
      Set Err_Rng = Range("B1")
    SigFig = WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(Log(Err_Rng) / Log(10), 1)
Select Case SigFig
    Case Is < -5: Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000E+00":       Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0E+00"
    Case -5:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0000000":         Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0E+00"
    Case -4:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000000":          Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000000"
    Case -3:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00000":           Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00000"
    Case -2:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0000":            Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0000"
    Case -1:    Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000":             Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000"
    Case 0:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00":              Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Case 1:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0":               Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0"
    Case 2:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.":                Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0."
    Case 3:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0":                 Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0"
    Case 4:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0":                 Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0"
    Case 5:     Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0":                 Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0"
    Case Is > 5: Val_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.000E+00":        Err_Rng.NumberFormat = "0.0E+00"
End Select
    If SigFig > 2 Then
        SigFig = SigFig - 2
        origval = Range("A1").Value2 ' A1 has Value2 = 423423
        val = 10 ^ SigFig * WorksheetFunction.Floor(Range("A1").Value2 / 10 ^ SigFig, 1)
        Range("A1").NumberFormat = """" & CStr(val) & """" ' Custom format = 423400
        Range("A1").FormulaR1C1 = origval ' recover Original value in FormulaR1C1
        
        Range("C1").Value2 = Range("A1").Value2 ' A1 still has Value2 = 423423, copy to C1
        
        origval = Range("B1").Value2 ' B1 has Value2 = 2341
        val = 10 ^ SigFig * WorksheetFunction.Floor(Range("B1").Value / 10 ^ SigFig, 1)
        Range("B1").NumberFormat = """" & CStr(val) & """" ' Custom format = 2300
        Range("B1").FormulaR1C1 = origval ' recover Original value in FormulaR1C1
        Range("D1").Value2 = Range("B1").Value2 ' A1 still has Value2 = 2341, copy to D1
   End If
```

Before execution:
[image]

After execution:
[image]